# Group By with Window Function instead of two Window Functions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with 2 columns: `time` and `id`. We think of the rows as sorted first by id, then by time.

```
╔════════╦══════════╗
║ time   ║ id       ║
╠════════╬══════════╣
║ 9:10   ║  1       ║
║ 9:20   ║  1       ║
║ 10:10  ║  1       ║
║ 11:30  ║  1       ║
║ 11:50  ║  1       ║
║ 10:20  ║  2       ║
║ 10:30  ║  2       ║
║ 11:20  ║  3       ║
║ 11:50  ║  3       ║
╚════════╩══════════╝
```

I want to select from it only the rows where their `id` is the same as the 'previous' row `id` and the time difference from the previous row is less than an hour.

This can be done by first creating a table where there is a 3rd column of the time differences to the previous row and a 4th column of the id differences, and only selecting the rows where the id_diff is 0 and the time_diff is above 1 hour.

But this method seems inelegant because I want to look at each `id` separately and inside each `id` to look at its times and check if the consecutive difference is above an hour. That'll reflect better the logic of looking at each id separately, because they are different entities.

So how can it be done with grouping on the id, instead of using window functions twice? I'm aware of `GROUP BY`'s existence.

The code that works, with two window functions:

```
SELECT auxiliary_table_with_lag_diffs.*
FROM (
    select info.*,
        time-lag(time) over (Order by id, time ) as diff_time,
        id-lag(id) over (order by id, time) as diff_id
    from info
    )auxiliary_table_with_lag_diffs
WHERE diff_time>'01:00:00'
    AND diff_id=0
ORDER BY id, time;
```

Comment: The first paragraph of your explanation conflicts with the second paragraph and the query.

Comment: Adding to this: How can "they" (I assume "the table's rows") be sorted? It's just a table and a table isn't sorted. You can sort them with ORDER BY in a query, but they aren't sorted per se.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need *one* analytic function call here: Get the previous time within the same ID.

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
  select info.*,
    time - lag(time) over (partition by id order by time) as diff_time
  from info
) auxiliary_table_with_lag_diffs
WHERE diff_time > interval '1 hour';
ORDER BY id, time;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to look at the previous row, then why are you ordering by `id` first?

```
SELECT i.*
FROM (select i.*, lag(time) over (order by time) as prev_time,
             lag(id) over (order by time) as prev_id
     from info i
     ) i 
WHERE time < prev_time + interval '1 hour' and id = prev_id
ORDER BY id, time;
```

If you don't want `prev_time` and `prev_id` in the output, just explicitly select the columns that you do want.

NOTE:  You might want `>` rather than `<` depending on your actual needs (the question is ambiguous).